# Prolog adds new line after execution

Tags: prolog, output, newline, swi-prolog

I have a prolog program, that takes input and makes output. 
The problem is, that after execution of program it adds a new line to the end.

For example when i redirect output to file, it still prints a new line. So i want get rid of this new line at the end.

Example:

**********: ~/Prolog$ ./filename < in.txt > out.txt

**********: ~/Prolog$

Im using swipl when compiling.

Comment: Where is your pro-gram?

Comment: Its in directory Prolog.